# Equivalent Symbol

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

If F1 <-> F2. Then does that means :

- F1 AND (negation F2) is unsatisfiable
- F1 OR (negation F2) is valid

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow$ means iff, or if and only if. It means that A$\Rightarrow$B __*and*__ B$\Rightarrow$A.

Comment: It means that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are either both true or both false. We say that they are *equivalent*.

Comment: See [Logical biconditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional)

Comment: Hint for the first exercise: if $((F_1 ↔ F_2) → ¬(F_1 ∧ ¬F_2))$ is a tautology, what can we conclude? If you show your work, we will be happy to verify your answers. If you do so, please remember to write mathematics between dollar signs like this `$x+1=1 \iff x=0$` $(x+1=1 \iff x=0).$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.

Forward:

---

From F1 <-> F2, we know that F1 and F2 are both true or both false, which in turn means $\neg F1$ has the same truth value as $\neg F2$.

1. By the law of noncontradiction, we have '*F1 AND (negation F1) is
   unsatisfiable*' and thus, '*F1 AND (negation F2) is unsatisfiable*'.
2. By the law of Excluded Middle, we have '*F1 OR (negation F1) is valid*' and thus, '*F1 OR (negation F2) is valid*'.

Backward:

---

1. '*F1 AND (negation F2) is unsatisfiable*' means either F1 or $\neg F2$ is false. That is, $\neg F1$ or F2 is true, which is equivalent to
   $F1\rightarrow F2$.
2. '*F1 OR (negation F2) is valid*' is equivalent to
   $F2\rightarrow F1$.

Combine the 2 points above and you can get $F1\leftrightarrow F2$.

Comment: Using the equivalence in the backward part is enough.